# error while calling the function when on-change event is fired

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

I was trying to build a todo app  and in which I am trying to call a function markComplete on every checkbox being checked or unchecked. it throws error saying **cannot read property 'completed' of undefined.**

what could be its solution??

```
<template>

  <div class="todos mt-4 mx-auto">
    <div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':todo.completed}" v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id">

      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete">
        {{todo.title}} 
        <button class="float-right del">&times;</button>
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['todo'],

  data (){
    return {
      todos:[
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Learn Vue',
          completed: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Creata a Todo App',
          completed: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Create BM news UI',
          completed: false
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    markComplete: function(){
      this.todo.completed = !this.todo.completed
    }
  }
}
```

just after running the app and clicking on the checkbox it consoles an error saying this...

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined"

found in

---> <TodoItem> at src/components/TodoItem.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'completed' of undefined
```

check the this image for the console screenshot

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfnuo.png)

although it works on this condition

`<input type="checkbox" v-on:change="todo.completed = !todo.completed">`

Comment: Can you provide a sample demo with the two components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a **collision of names**, or **change the todo name of the property** like

`props: ['todoProp']`

or change the todo in the v-for like

```
<div class="todo-item" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':currentTodo.completed}" v-for="currentTodo in todos" :key="currentTodo.id">
```

Comment: Sorry mate it didn;t worked. It still logging the same error

Answer (score 0):

What;s a purpose of **props: ['todo']**? This name conflicts in a template with **v-for="todo in todos"**. If you just wish to change the **completed** prop of an item of a *todos* list then just do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="todo.completed">
```

If you wish to do additional code on change todo.completed then you can do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete(todo)">
...
methods: {
    markComplete: function(todo){
      todo.completed = !todo.completed
      // do some work
    }
  }
```